# Django-CKEditor Image Upload

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I've currently installed Django-CKEditor and have my own custom toolbar.

I'm struggling to find how to enable image uploading. When clicking the Image button, I can only upload via URL. I know that, in the plugin, there are views to handle file browsing and uploading but I'm not sure how to activate or use these.

There is sparse documentation on the plugin so I am reaching out for your help!

https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I had mentioned in my question - Django CKEditor comes with a number of URLs to handle the viewing and browsing of images. The subsequent steps to activate this with your editor require you to add a filebrowserBrowseUrl when activating the editor and setting it to the appropriate /upload/ and /browse/ URLs.

See more here:

http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/

Answer (score 6):

In the current version (5) you can use `RichTextUploadingField` instead of `RichTextField`, which enables uploading and browse files button.

Previously you have to install `django-uploader` package.

Comment: when i tried to use RichTextUploadingField instead of RichTextField the text editor disappears

Answer (score 3):

settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class ModelName(models.Model):
    text_field_name = RichTextUploadingField()
```

Comment: dont forget out `path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),` in base urls