# django CKEditor not showing image upload

Tags: django, ckeditor, image-uploading, django-ckeditor

In a django application, target is to edit e-mail template in a WYSIWYG editor.
Using CKEditor works fine, but images can only be included via URL, not via upload.

A similar question is asked here:
[Django-CKEditor Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017553/django-ckeditor-image-upload)

What is not covered there is the case where a Form Field is used, *not* a Model Field. Also the accepted solution is not really explained.

Current code:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

class EmailConfirmationTemplateForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.email_template = kwargs.pop('email_template')
        kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})['email_template'] = self.email_template
        super(EmailConfirmationTemplateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.fields['email_template'] = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

Template code:

```
...
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
</form>
```

Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    ...
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'cke-uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'
```

**Question is: How to have the possibility to upload images in this WYSIWYG editor?**

Version Info: django 1.8.16, django-ckeditor 5.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Am not very sure about that django-version, but now ckeditor supports uploading picures by using its `RichTextUploadingField`. So for using it for models its quite simple. Go to your `app_name/models.py` and import `RichTextUploadingField`. Then instead of using something like:

```
article_content = models.TextField()
```

use this

```
article_content = models.RichTextUploadingField()
```